# QLPreviewController is crashing in iOS5.1 while continuous zooming and scrolling of PDF

Tags: ios, ipad, qlpreviewcontroller

QLPreviewController in iOS 5.1 is crashing after scrolling and zooming the pdf shown in controller.
When I zoom and scroll continuously, it starts giving warning in log

```
Ignoring call to [UIPanGestureRecognizer setTranslation:inView:] since gesture recognizer is not active.
```

and it crashes.
Well i've not checked in other iOS versions,but in 5.1 its crashing

Comment: she test on ipad2 ios5.1 . .  may it also occur in ipad1

Comment: i was presenting QLPreviewController in modalView now displaying it as UIModalPresentationFullScreen rather than UIModalPresentationPageSheet in modalPresentationStyle solved the problem.